# Use web hosting as a external email server

Tags: web-hosting, email, server

I have this question is it stupid to use a shared hosting to host my domain for only my email address not for a website.

Answer (score 3):

It's not inherently stupid, especially if you think you might eventually have a web site also, but it *is* probably a waste of money. There are companies that provide email-only hosting for significantly less than the web+email hosting that you wouldn't even be using most of. Just do a basic search for "email hosting." It's likely the web host you're already looking at, or your registrar, have services for it.

Comment: Cheaper and probably better on many levels...

Comment: Yeah, I know that some hosts don't especially like mail hosting and would quietly prefer you make separate arrangements for it. But it's kind of anecdotal so I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need hosting of some sort. My suggestion would be get an email specific hosting service. For example, [rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/) offers email hosting for $2/month.